# Store a collection as a node in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a query that returns two variables A & B. A returns collections that contain a variable number of values. B is a mathematical score related to each collection. I want to store A as nodes in the database with property B. Then if possible to check each node of A against the other nodes and create a relationship if both the values of B> some number. Is this possible in Neo4j?
An example of what my A and B looks like

```
MATCH (t:Trans)-[:CONTAINS]->(i2:Item), (t:Trans)-[:CONTAINS]->(i1:Item), (t:Trans)-[:CONTAINS]->(i3:Item) 
WITH i1, i2, i3, COUNT(*) as c
WHERE c>100
WITH COLLECT({i1: i1, i2:i2, i3:i3, c: c}) AS data
UNWIND data AS d
WITH COLLECT({i1:d.i1.I_ID, i2:d.i2.I_ID, i3:d.i3.I_ID}) as Itemset, d
RETURN Itemset, d.c as NumTransactions
```

```
A                       B
{a,b,c}                 45
{e,f}                   23
{a,e,f}                 12
{d}                     89
```

Comment: What is your existing query (which you presumably want to modify)? Is what you call a "collection" actually a map or a list? Also, it does not make sense to create relationships between all nodes that satisfy some common criterion (if there are N such nodes, then you'd have to create almost (N**2)/2 relationships). There are other efficient ways to handle what seems to be your use case.

Comment: The collection is a list as it's the output of a cypher collect statement. As for the relationships part I misunderstood the parameter calculation. I'll be able to handle that myself. So if I can figure out how to store each list as a node it'll be fine

Comment: Can you show your actual query that returns `A` and `B`? Also, can you share what your use cases are? It is not clear if you *should* be storing a list per collection, or if you should instead make each element in a collection a distinct node (e.g., a unique node for the `f` element that is shared between all collections).

Comment: To generate association rules between each set. I have edited the question to show the query.

Comment: Please just tell me how to store the list as a node anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[UPDATED]

Your query is doing a lot of unnecessary work. Also, your `Itemset` is always a list containing a single map, so having a list seems unnecessary.

This query should be equivalent (except that `Itemset` is just a map):

```
MATCH (t:Trans)-[:CONTAINS]->(i2:Item), (t)-[:CONTAINS]->(i1:Item), (t)-[:CONTAINS]->(i3:Item) 
WITH {i1: i1.I_ID, i2: i2.I_ID, i3: i3.I_ID} AS Itemset, COUNT(*) as NumTransactions
WHERE NumTransactions > 100
RETURN Itemset, NumTransactions
```

It feels to me like you should not be storing the `Itemset` in an `A` node. Here is an example of how to create relationships from each `Item` to the same `B` node:

```
MATCH (t:Trans)-[:CONTAINS]->(i2:Item), (t)-[:CONTAINS]->(i1:Item), (t)-[:CONTAINS]->(i3:Item) 
WITH i1.I_ID AS id1, i2.I_ID AS id2, i3.I_ID AS id3, COUNT(*) as c
WHERE c > 100
MERGE (b:B {numTransactions: c})
MERGE (i1)-[:FOO]->(b)
MERGE (i2)-[:FOO]->(b)
MERGE (i3)-[:FOO]->(b)
```

Comment: If I was to store it this way wouldn't it be better to use the already existing i1, i2 AND I3 in some way rather than creating new nodes a1, a2 and a3 that contain the same information as them? And just out of academic interest how would you store the list anyway?

Answer (score 0):

The second part looks easy enough:

- give the A nodes a distinct label
- `MATCH (n:A_LABEL) WHERE a.b_property > 35 RETURN (n)`
- iterate over the list, checking for a relationship from the first one to each of the rest, and creating one if it's not there.

Could the values change over time? If so, you may need a corresponding function that removes this kind of relationship from nodes whose score is now <= the threshold value.

It's harder to advise about how to store the collections, without knowing more about the problem you're solving.

Comment: No the value will not change. It's just as the question says. I need to store each collection as a distinct node of it's own, because I need the relation between each set.